# Summation over specific tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I would like to write a function that would, given a positive integer $n$, compute the following:

$S_n = \sum_{(x,y,z)} a_{(x,y,z)} f(x,y,z)$, where the sum runs over all tuples $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z = n$, and $x,y,z$ take values in {$0,1,...,n$}. The ultimate goal is to pass this function trough `Solve` to determine the coefficients $a_{(x,y,z)}$ with some other conditions from the problem.

My main problem is generating the appropriate tuples in a way that I could then pass through `Sum`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you already seen `FrobeniusSolve[]`?

Comment: I have not, I'll look it up

Comment: Yep, it looks like it works, thanks!

Comment: @johnny If you have a solution in hand, please write up an answer to your question, so it does not remain dangling for future users.

Comment: As @J.M. says, `FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], n]` would do; but if you can make any use of permutational equivalence, then `IntegerPartitions[n, {n}, Range[0, n]]` may also help as it generates a vastly smaller list (which needs to be permuted, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @MarcoB, here is my solution, using `FrobeniusSolve`:

```
Frobenius[n_] := FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, n];
Sol[n_] :=
Sum[a[Part[Frobenius[n], i] /. List -> Sequence]
*OrderN[Part[Frobenius[n], i] /. List -> Sequence],
{i, 1, Length[Frobenius[n]]}]
```

In the code, corresponds to the $f(x,y,z)$ in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up! (+1)